# Can't preserve encoding text in Python

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to submit text from a file to a form on a site with mechanize but the text doesn't look good there, if i copy-paste looks like this:

```
                                   ████                                     
                                  █⌡⌡⌡⌡████                                 
                                 █⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡█████                            
                                █⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡████⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡████                        
                                █⌡⌡⌡██    ██⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡█████                   
                               █⌡⌡⌡⌡█      █⌡⌡⌡⌡██⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡⌡████
```

If i use the code Python looks like this:

```
                              ����                                     
                              ���������                                 
                             ���������������                            
                            ��������������������                        
                            ������    ���������������                   
                           ������      ������������������               
        �����             ������        ���������������������           
    �������������        ��������      ���������������������������
```

Probably is something about encoding,can't make it work. In the original file,textfile.txt, encoding is OEM-US, i googled this and is cp437.

```
def functionaa(linksite, text):
    import mechanize 
    import cookielib
    # Browser 
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    # Cookie Jar
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar() 
    br.set_cookiejar(cj) 
    # Browser options 
    br.set_handle_equiv(True) 
    br.set_handle_gzip(True) 
    br.set_handle_redirect(True) 
    br.set_handle_referer(True) 
    br.set_handle_robots(False) 
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1) 
    edit = br.open(link)
    html1 = edit.read()
    br.select_form(nr=0) 
    br.form['textcode'] = "[pre]%s[/pre]" % text
    br.submit() 

f=open(r'E:\ABC\textfile.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
functionaa("http://site.com", content)
```

Comment: I have ActivePython 2.5, ASCII from what i know, every 2.x python is ASCII, only 3.x is unicode.

Comment: Sorry about the misleading question. Anyway, you can change the encoding of the text after you've read it. Simply decode and encode it it (`str.decode('cp437').encode('utf-8')`). That will work in most cases. And by most cases. I mean sites.

Comment: I just added content.decode('cp437').encode('utf-8') and it's the same on the site :(

Comment: *Text* is a human concept. Computers transfer (and represent) text via sequences of bytes encoded in some *scheme*. You should specify what you are trying to accomplish, and how do you actually test your code to see that it fails. Printing to a terminal windows is not a very good test, you know, especially in this case

Comment: Well, I run that script with python and check on the site to see if it's how i want. I know for sure that it's been edited on site, it says in log, I am not printing on CMD. It may be ASCII, but if I try to encode to ascii "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 39-42: ordinal not in range(128)"

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, looks like the problem it's with mechanize. In CMD i can print it as I want just like this, without unicode..

```
content = file.read()
print content
```

But when i send it through mecanize, on the site it's not the same.

With ignore flag everything is skipped but text.
The errors says, ascii can't encode those chars..

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to upload only the file contents as if the user manually typed it in a text control, you should first ensure that the [charset](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) assumed by the processing agent can represent your *strange* characters. If that's the case, you can pass to step 2 and read the file contents in a native Python string in this way:

```
file = open(filename, 'rb')
content = unicode(file.read(), 'cp437')
file.close()
# Now use "content" to fill the form
```

Instead, this is how [you should upload](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html) your file:

```
def upload(action, filename):
  br = mechanize.Browser()
  br.form.add_file(open(filename, 'rb'), 'text/plain; charset=cp437', filename)
  # Do your work...
  br.submit()
```

Note that I [opened](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) the file in binary mode, so no trasformation is applied to its bytes. Note also that I specified the supposed encoding in the MIME type. Now it's up to the server code to handle the transcoding (if any).

Comment: The thing is that where I want to put that text is a textbox, i don't need to upload the file, I need to read it and send the content to the textbox.

Comment: If i open the file with notepad++ and chose other encoding than OEM-US, looks like hell. Only if i copy-paste from OEM-US looks like the first post, from other encoding is just like the script does it.

Comment: Because the very same sequence of bytes represent different characters depending on the decoding scheme. See the updated answer to build a unicode string (which likely can represent your *strange* text) out of your file.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 44-47: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Can you please post your code on [gist](http://gist.github.com). Also, upload your file somewhere, either verbatim or in some encoding

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Martzy303/7f11d47519de5bc73dc3 and the file http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1HcqxZVu

Comment: The file on pastebin is served in UTF-8, and it doesn't seem the one you posted in your question. Also, I don't have an account on filelist.ro, so I can't run your code and can't tell what's wrong. Even the error you posted is meaningless without its stack trace

Comment: Ok, i changed to utf-8. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Sawyer\Desktop\test.py", line 32,in <module>
    content = unicode(file.read(), 'utf8')
  File "C:\Python25\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 39-40: invalid data

I don't think it's about the site, with copy-paste it's ok.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ps5UFRSz
 And this is the part of the page source code with that textarea.

Comment: That is useless. Please upload your **original** file somewhere

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18613192/chwp-xvid-sml.nfo
On my dropbox. On this file I get that error.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I'm able to run the first code snippet in my answer, so it means that I can get a `unicode` string from your file, and can even print and interpolate it. I can't say anything about the Mechanize part because it's impossible for me to test, however you should try at least the first part to be sure you can get the right characters from the input file.